# Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\new Client ID.txt

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

I am using CSOM to upload a file to Share Point list.It says

> "Server Error in '/App' Application.Could not find file
>   '`c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\new Client ID.txt'` "

Here is my code, UserCV is the id of the fileUpload that I am using.
Thanks by advance

```
            FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();                
            newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(UserCV.FileName);
            newFile.Url = Path.GetFileName(UserCV.FileName);               
            List docs = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List_Name");
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);               
            clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```